# Iterate JSON with Ruby and get a key,value in an array

Tags: ruby, json, iteration

I'm getting some trouble with this JSON:

```
{
    "ENAX-BRANCHESM-10" :
    {
        "repo":"test-ASO",
        "PATH":"/tmp/pruebaAlvaro",
        "ARTIFACTS":"example1.jar,another_one.jar,and_another.jar",
        "uri":"http://server:8081/artifactory/test-ASO",
        "created":"A705663"

    },
    "QZQP-QZQPMAN-16" : {
        "repo": "test-ASO",
        "PATH": "/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2",
        "ARTIFACTS": "test543.jar,thisisa.jar,yesanother.jar",
        "uri": "http://server:8081/artifactory/test-ASO",
        "created": "A705663"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to iterate through the lists to get the PATH and the ARTIFACTS values for each list, in the example there are two lists, but really there are dozens. The purpose is to know which artifact is going to be deployed to its own path. For example:

```
/tmp/pruebaAlvaro
example1.jar

/tmp/pruebaAlvaro 
another_one.jar

/tmp/pruebaAlvaro 
and_another.jar

/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2 
test543.jar

/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2 
thisisa.jar

/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2 
yesanother.jar
```

After I searched deeply I still cannot get the solution.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json = JSON.parse(your_json)
values = json.map { |_, v| { v[:PATH] => v[:ARTIFACTS].split(',') } }
```

You'll get the nice hash

```
{
  '/tmp/pruebaAlvaro' => ['example1.jar', 'another_one.jar', ...],
  '/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2' => [...]
}
```

And, you can iterate over it:

```
values.each do |path, artifacts|
  artifacts.each do |artifact|
    puts path
    puts artifact
  end
  puts
end
```

You'll get the same output, which you provided in the question

Comment: Thank you asiniy, but I'm getting this error:

parse_json.rb:103: private method `split' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `map'
        from parse_json.rb:103:in `each'
        from parse_json.rb:103:in `map'
        from parse_json.rb:103

Is it possible that your solution requires additional ruby modules/gems?

Comment: Can you show me your 100-110 lines of parse_json.rb?

Comment: Mainly there is several commented(#) lines

parseoJSON = JSON.parse res.body
#contentsJSON = parseoJSON["ENAX-BRANCHESM-10"]["PATH"]
#artifactsJSON = parseoJSON["ENAX-BRANCHESM-10"]["ARTIFACTS"]
#puts contentsJSON + " debe recibir " + artifactsJSON

values = parseoJSON.map { |_, v| { v[:PATH] => v[:ARTIFACTS].split(',') } }
puts values

Comment: It seems in one of your items `v[:ARTIFACTS]` is `null`, you just need to convert it to a string before splitting, like this: `v[:ARTIFACTS].to_s.split(',')`.

Comment: Let me check my code and I'll feedback you, thank you both

Comment: Here is the code you requested @asiniy
    url = URI.parse(uridownJSON)
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
    res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
      http.request(req)
    }
    puts res.body

    parseoJSON = JSON.parse res.body
    values = parseoJSON.map {|_, v| {v[:PATH] => v[:ARTEFACTOS].split(',') } }
    puts values

Comment: @asiniy did you test your solution with the json as a local file? I'm testing on a remote file and it seems that the json = JSON.parse(your_json) is not getting the info as it should be

Comment: Ok, I found very useful your answer and I finally got that some variables' behavior was not the expected. Thank you for your effort!